# Order of computation on parallel processing

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing

Given an unsorted array, I have read in an article that n-square processors can be used to get the maximum element of the array in O(1) complexity. Can anybody explain the mechanics behind it?

Comment: Reference for the article, please?

Comment: Are you sure it's not a probabilistic algorithm?

Comment: It's possible on a concurrent random-access machine.

Comment: @arshajii: Please, be more specific. Any future info?

Comment: Please go to slide 50 of this PowerPoint http://www.cs.haifa.ac.il/~oren/Publications/RMQSlides.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mechanics behind the algorithm is based on what I only can call a dirty trick. Namely, we allow all processors to write simultaneously to the same shared memory location. If they all write the same value, the result is considered well-defined.

This can be used to implement parallel-AND and parallel-OR operators. Here's for example the parallel-OR:

```
result := false
for i in 0 to N-1 parallel do
  if a[i] then
    result := a[i]
```

We also allow simultaneous reads.

Here's the MAX algorithm:

```
N := a.length

for i in 0 to N-1 parallel do
    m[i] := true

for i in 0 to N-1 parallel do
  for j in 0 to N-1 parallel do
    if a[i] < a[j]               /* dirty trick: simultaneous read by many processors */
      then m[i] := false         /* dirty trick: many processors write to m[i] at once */

for i in 0 to N-1 parallel do
    if m[i]
        then max := a[i]         /* dirty trick: many processors write to max at once */

return max
```

The abstract architecture that allows for these tricks is called [CRCW PRAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_random-access_machine).

Answer (score 0):

This is a follow-up to |V|ad's answer (which was deleted),

You use an additional array of size `n` (lets call it B),
Now you use `n-1` processors to compare any element `a[i], i=0,...,n-1` with all the other elements `a[0],...,a[i-1],a[i+1],...,a[n-1]`, each processor `j={1,...,n-1}` that find that that finds that `a[0] > a[j]`, will apply `B[i]=B[i]+1`, in addition, it will check if `B[i]=n-1`, if so, it will announce that element i is the maximal element.

Comment: This looks like it has the same problem though, how will multiple processors do `B[i] = B[i] + 1` at once?